# Finding control bifurcation parameter for a simple subcritical equation.

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

$\dot{x}=x-rx^{3}=f\left ( r,x \right )$

Attempt to find the control parameter:

$f'\left ( r,x \right )=1-3rx^{2}$

$f'\left ( r,x \right )=0 \Rightarrow  1-3rx^{2}\Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{3r}}$

Now, $f\left ( r,x \right )=0 \Rightarrow 1-rx^{2}=0$

Substituting $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{3r}}$ into $f\left ( r,x \right )=0 \Rightarrow 1-rx^{2}=0$ doesn't give me anything meaningful due to the fact that the variable r is cancelled.

Is there a trick to this or am I overlooking something?

Comment: One could notice that there are two constant solutions to the homogenous ODE you mention $ \dot{x} = x – rx^3 $,
$$ x = 0$$ and $$ x = \sqrt {\frac{1}{r}}$$
The fact that one exists only for non.-negative $r$ immediately signals a significant change in the system’s behaviour when $r$ crosses the real axis.

Comment: @Anaedonist there are three if you included the other negative root of the reciprocal.

Comment: indeed, sorry for my sloppiness.